# Html Agility Pack: replacing script tags

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I want to replace JQuery `script` tag in an html string by the its code. means removing the `script` tag with the `src` attribute set to for example "scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" to a `script` tag containing the current source code of JQuery.

I create a new node using this code :

```
HtmlNode node = new HtmlNode(HtmlNodeType.Element, htmlDocument, index);
node.Name = "script";
node.PrependChild(HtmlNode.CreateNode(jQuerySourceCodeString));
```

no matter what i do to the `jQuerySourceCodeString` it is always truncated to this :

```
<script>/*!
 * jQuery JavaScript Library v1.9.1
 * http://jquery.com/
 *
 * Includes Sizzle.js
 * http://sizzlejs.com/
 *
 * Copyright 2005, 2012 jQuery Foundation, Inc. and other contributors
 * Released under the MIT license
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * Date: 2013-2-4
 */
(function( window, undefined ) {

// Can't do this because several apps including ASP.NET trace
// the stack via arguments.caller.callee and Firefox dies if
// you try to trace through "use strict" call chains. (#13335)
// Support: Firefox 18+
//"use strict";
var
    // The deferred used on DOM ready
    readyList,

    // A central reference to the root jQuery(document)
    rootjQuery,

    // Support: IE</script>
```

which is clearly not the code we can find [here](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js)

what am I doing wrong ?

**Update :**

1 - I can not user `InnerHtml` since it tries to read it as html.

2 - The `HtmlNode.CreateNode` method breaks when it finds this "<", it thinks that its the beginning of a tag, but it is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering your problem is how to append a `script` node using to the parsed html document (*because you want to remove the existing script node, retrieve the source from the script src's uri, and append a new one with the results*), I created a sample to reproduce what you want to do.

1. I took the [`cdn` for jquery 1.9.1](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js) and saved it into a local file
2. I then tried to append it to the html document, under a `script` node

I tried some attempts with `HtmlAgilityPack`, but the resulting html always had a *trailing garbage*, looking like

```
</div></10></=></9></=8></"></$1></(?!area|br|col|embed|hr|img|input|link|meta|param)(([\w:-]+)[^></(?:"></use></9></table></tfoot></thead></tbody></table></tbody></9></=></"></[\w\w]+></tag></\></([\w-]+)\s*\></number></9></9></1.9.8+></10></=8></script>
```

I then gave up and tried another html parser I (more) often use - `AngleSharp`.
With it, I get a correct resulting html.

Here are the code snippets for both attempts:

**HtmlAgilityPack:**

```
string html = @"
    <html>
    <head><title>SO Question</title></head>
    <body>
        <div>
            text text text
        </div>
    </body>

    <script>
        var a = 10;
    </script>
    </html>
";

var jsCode = File.ReadAllText("D:/jquery-1.12.4.js", Encoding.UTF8);

HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

HtmlNode jsNode = new HtmlNode(HtmlNodeType.Element, doc, 0);
jsNode.Name = "script";
jsNode.InnerHtml = jsCode;

doc.DocumentNode.InsertAfter(jsNode, doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("body"));

File.WriteAllText("D:/jsCodeOut.html", doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml);
```

**AngleSharp:**

```
string html = @"
    <html>
    <head><title>SO Question</title></head>
    <body>
        <div>
            text text text
        </div>
    </body>

    <script>
        var a = 10;
    </script>
    </html>
";

var jsCode = File.ReadAllText("D:/jquery-1.12.4.js", Encoding.UTF8);

HtmlParser hp = new HtmlParser();
var parsedHtml = hp.Parse(html);

var scriptNode = parsedHtml.CreateElement("script");
scriptNode.InnerHtml = jsCode;

parsedHtml.DocumentElement.AppendChild(scriptNode);

File.WriteAllText("D:/angleSharpOutput.html", parsedHtml.DocumentElement.InnerHtml);
```

---

**Conclusion:**

If you need to do it exclusively with `HtmlAgilityPack`, then my post was ultimately of no help. Otherwise, try `AngleSharp` and you have solved your problem.

Comment: it will be interesting nevertheless if someone finds the solution using `HtmlAgilityPack` :)

Comment: i think the only solution is to modify their source code.

Answer (score 1):

With `HtmlAgilityPack` you can use textNode:

```
jsNode.AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode(jsCode));
```